# swift/parse: error when setting Parse data to labels

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uilabel

What I am trying to do is to have data from Parse be retrieved from columns by object order. All labels are connected to their respective outlets and all of the outputs retrieve their correct data.

[image]

[image]

When I run it and open a cell in the tableview it crashes and gives me **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC>I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)** on this line: `self.navBar.topItem?.title = output1` if I select the first cell, and then on this line: `self.navBar.topItem?.title = output1b` if I select the second cell.

Here is the full function:

`firstObject` is grabbing the first object in the `"eventsdetail"` column

`secondObject` is grabbing the second object in the `"eventsdetail"` column

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "eventsdetail")
    let runkey = query.orderByAscending("ID")
    runkey.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                for object in objects {

                    var firstObject = objects[0]
                    var secondObject = objects[1]

                    let output1 = firstObject.objectForKey("navTitle") as! String!
                    let output2 = firstObject.objectForKey("articleTitle") as! String!
                    let output3 = firstObject.objectForKey("written") as! String!
                    let output4 = firstObject.objectForKey("date") as! String!
                    let output5 = firstObject.objectForKey("article") as! String!

                    let output1b = secondObject.objectForKey("navTitle") as! String!
                    let output2b = secondObject.objectForKey("articleTitle") as! String!
                    let output3b = secondObject.objectForKey("written") as! String!
                    let output4b = secondObject.objectForKey("date") as! String!
                    let output5b = secondObject.objectForKey("article") as! String!

                    if indexPath.row == 0 {
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("0a", sender: nil)
                        self.tableview.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
                        self.navBar.topItem?.title = output1
                        self.articleTitle.text = output2
                        self.writtenBy.text = output3
                        self.date.text = output4
                        self.article.text = output5

                    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("0a", sender: nil)
                        self.tableview.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
                        self.navBar.topItem?.title = output1b
                        self.articleTitle.text = output2b
                        self.writtenBy.text = output3b
                        self.date.text = output4b
                        self.article.text = output5b

                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

If there is an easier way of doing this, please mention it, if not try to just solve this method's problem. I know it isn't the cleanest way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of how you Parse your data but if it can help you, here's how I would do:

```
//
//  Test.swift
//  Test
//
//  Created by Charles-Olivier Demers on 16-01-04.
//

import UIKit
//import Parse

class EventViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    private var _info = [EventDetails]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        fetchData()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("0a", sender: nil)
        self.tableview.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        self.navBar.topItem?.title.text = _info[indexPath.row].navTitle()
        self.articleTitle.text = _info[indexPath.row].articleTitle()
        self.writtenBy.text = _info[indexPath.row].writtenBy()
        self.date.text = _info[indexPath.row].date()
        self.article.text = _info[indexPath.row].article()
    }


    func fetchData() {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "eventsDetails")

        query.orderByAscending("ID")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if let objects = objects {

                    for object in objects {
                        let navTitleObject = object["navTitle"] as! String
                        let articleTitleObject = object["articleTitle"] as! String
                        let writtenByObject = object["writtenByObject"] as! String
                        let dateObject = object["dateObject"] as! String
                        let articleObject = object["articleObject"] as! String

                        _info.append(EventDetails(navTitle: navTitleObject, articleTitle: articleTitleObject, writtenBy: writtenByObject, date: dateObject, article: articleObject))

                    }

                }
            }

            else {
                print("Error #\(error!.code)")
            }
        }
    }
}

class EventDetails {

    private var _navTitle: String!
    private var _articleTitle: String!
    private var _writtenBy: String!
    private var _date: String!
    private var _article: String!

    init(navTitle: String, articleTitle: String, writtenBy: String, date: String, article: String) {
        self._navTitle = navTitle
        self._article = articleTitle
        self._writtenBy = writtenBy
        self._date = date
        self._article = article
    }

    func navTitle() -> String {
        return _navTitle
    }

    func articleTitle() -> String {
        return _articleTitle
    }

    func writtenBy() -> String {
        return _writtenBy
    }

    func date() -> String {
        return _date
    }

    func article() -> String {
        return _article
    }

}
```

First of all, I would create a class named EventDetails. This class will take all the property of EventsDetails class on Parse. So when you fetch your data, you append the data you fetch in an array of EventDetails class in Swift.

After that in your

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

you take the value in your EventDetails array with the indexPath.row and you fill your Table View.

That is how I would do.

Comment: it's giving me errors telling me to remove the `()` next to all of the items in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and if I do it says **Cannot assign value of type 'UILabel/UITextView/UINavigationBar' to type 'String?'**

Comment: Your getter for: navTitle in: _info[indexPath.row].navTitle() for example, should return a String. Try to add .text to the element where the error occurs:

self.navBar.topItem?.title should be:

self.navBar.topItem?.title.text = _info[indexPath.row].navTitle()

Comment: okay that fixed it. now on the line of `_info.append(EventsViewController(navTitleObject, articleTitleObject, writtenByObject, dateObject, articleTitleObject))` it is giving me a error saying **Cannot invoke initializer for type 'EventsViewController' with an argument list of type '(String, String, String, String, String)'**

Comment: @Hunter 
The declaration for the class EventsViewController should be:

class EventViewController {

init(navTitle: String, articleTitle: String, writtenBy: String, date: String, articleTitle: String) {
 // ..
}
}

Comment: I would recommend going back and reviewing your answer, I have already found several coding mistakes. afterwards I will look at it.

Comment: Did you make a class EventsViewController? or EventsDetail?

Comment: I added this `private var _info = [EventsDetail]()` unless I need to do something else, but you should have seen that in the code I posted above.

Comment: So you don't have a .swift file with a class EventsDetail? If no, create a class named EventsDetail. Inside of the class add the property of your object (navTitle, articleTitle, ...). After that, add the init I send you. (Inside the init do this for each property: self.navTitle = navTitle, ...). After the init, add the getter for your property (func navTitle() -> String { return self.navTitle }

Comment: I do have a class, but it is actually called EventsViewController. if you have other code you don't have above please edit and add it to your answer.

Comment: Do your EventsViewController class contain the tableview delegate and all that stuff? If yes you need to make an other class EventsDetail for example. Copy and paste your code

Comment: I made a class now called EventDetailViewController does the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` go in the EventDetailViewController or EventsViewController?

Comment: what do I put as my `super.init` because I'm getting an error at the bottom of `init(navTitle: String, articleTitle: String, writtenBy: String, date: String, article: String)` that says **Super.init isn't called before returning from initializer**

Comment: Create a .Swift file call: EventDetails and inside add the EventDetails class code that I provided in my answer. I think it would solve the problem

Comment: I have done that already and I am still getting the `super.init` error that is posted above. I had to also add `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }` but even this doesn't fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you get this problem. Can you copy on pastebin.com your code and send me the link i would look

Comment: I have a viewcontroller for the tableview and a viewcontroller for the detailview. what should their classes be?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question...What is your detailview? And what do you mean by 'what should their classes be?'

Comment: I'm talking about the actual view controllers in the storyboard. what classes should the view controllers be linked to?

Comment: The viewController (where your tableView is) in your storyboard should be linked with the EventDetailViewController. Also the delegate&datasource of your tableView should be linked with the EventDetailViewController. So in the EventDetailViewController class, modify this header: class EventDetailViewController: UIViewController to

class EventDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableVieDataSource

And dont forget to link the tableView in the storyboard

Comment: shouldn't the EventsViewController be linked with the viewcontroller that has the tableview? the EventsViewController.swift holds everything for my tableview. so what I did was set the EventsViewController to the viewcontroller with the tableview and the EventDetailViewController.swift with the viewcontroller that is segued to and that has all the labels. I am now getting the **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION** error on `self.navBar.topItem?.title = _info[indexPath.row].navTitle()`

Comment: The file are probally bad linked or your _info[].navTitle() return nil

Comment: Quick I dont't see problem with it. Doe's the problem occur on the transition of two view controller?

Comment: The error occurs when I tap on the tableviewcell to segue to the detailviewcontroller.

Comment: Show me your DetailViewController

Comment: In your func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) of the EventsViewController class the first line do: print(_info.count) and if the result is 0, it's because you have nothing in the array so it's might be your problem

Comment: The result is 2 but also under that it says **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: When you got the fatal error, it's because you are trying to get a value that do not exist. What is the correct line of the error?

Comment: `self.navBar.topItem?.title = _info[indexPath.row].navTitle()`

Comment: Oh! I found why you get the problem, that's probably because you fetch your info with query.findObjectsInBackground() and you click the cells before the data is store in the _info[]

Comment: what would I do to fix this then? please update it in your answer.

Comment: Before you come to EventsViewController class, call the query and store the info in an array. Try this

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: When you load the program, fetch the data and store it in a global array. Using global variable is not the better way but try this and if it work maybe we would do something else

Comment: could you either update your answer or give me a link to your pastebin? I think it will be easier if you just show me in code what to do rather than having me just guess what to do.

Comment: I don't need to modify the code! You just have to copy/paste your fetch data outside of your viewcontroller and call it when your program start. Store the data in a global array and use this array in your viewcontroller

Comment: On parse do you have some value empty?

Comment: I moved my `fetchData()` to outside of the EventsViewController class and I am still getting the same error. I have checked the class names of the Parse data and they are correct. so I'm not sure what the problem is now. here is an updated version of my EventsViewController: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6PQ29ijm)

Comment: When you print _info in the tableView( didSelectRowAtIndexPath ) do you get something for each row?

Comment: But do you have a value for each "column" of each row? I presume no because you have a nil value but check wich value it is

Comment: I do, I even have a picture of the columns from Parse in my question above, take a look at it.

Comment: I think it is all of them because if I comment one out it is the next one that has the error. how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you send me all your project? and a fresh screenshot of your parse table?

Comment: [EventsViewController](http://pastebin.com/5QPxuy0f), [EventDetailViewController](http://pastebin.com/hNxTAtng), [Fresh Screenshot of Parse Table](http://imgur.com/1gft8sK)

Comment: But can you pass me the whole project so i can execute it

Comment: just make a new project and use the code I have given you. I don't want to share it because of privacy issues in the rest of the project.

Comment: I understand, but I don't want to do all the project... I hope you will find a solution. Have a great day!

Comment: I am making a example version of just the tableview. I'll send it to you when it is done uploading.

Comment: what is your email? I'll send you a link to a Dropbox download.

Comment: charles-olivierdemers@hotmail.com

Comment: Give me your email I will send you back the project working

Comment: hunter.developer@aol.com

Comment: In the EventViewController I explain what I change